# MySQL DATE_ADD INTERVAL

Tags: mysql, intervals, dateadd

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET date = DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 17 HOUR), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
        WHERE idevent = '2'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

I want to add 7 days to the date, but have the time aspect of datetime manually set. I have the code above, which works for the hour, but as soon as I add minutes it errors saying SQL syntax error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need another `DATE_ADD()` at the front of that expression, since you're doing two additions.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET date = DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK), INTERVAL 17 HOUR), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) WHERE idevent = '2'");
//-------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

What keeps you from adding `17*60+30 Minutes` and keeping the code readable?

Answer (score -1):

4 open '(' and 5 closing ')'. Disbalans.

Comment: Its not an answer. It *should* be a comment.

Comment: it is answer that explains why author gets syntax error, which prevents him to add minutes.